# Pandas import error

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, easy-install

I tried installing pandas using `easy_install` and it claimed that it successfully installed the pandas package in my Python Directory.

I switch to IDLE and try `import pandas` and it throws me the following error -

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas\hashtable.c:20282)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling`

Please help me diagnose the error.

FYI: I have already installed the `numpy` package

Comment: Can you post the output of the following lines, from this gist: https://gist.github.com/nipunreddevil/5956172; you can leave out scikit-learn lines

Comment: This is an install error.  Are you able to use `pip install pandas`?

Comment: @NipunBatra : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    print "OS:",platform.platform()
NameError: name 'platform' is not defined

Comment: I have been waiting for a solution to my problem. I would really appreciate if some one can help me fix the problem.

Comment: Did this ever get fixed? I am having the same problem, when I --upgrade pandas and numpy it says "Requirement already up to date..."

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you interrupted pandas install , retry using pip :

First install pip (if you haven't done it already) :

```
easy_install pip
```

then reinstall pandas:

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You know that output error you got when you tried running @nipun-batra's script?

Well, you got it because you have to first:

```
import platform
```

before you can run:

```
platform.platform()
```

I know this because I--about 10 minutes ago--got the same error when trying to run the same script. The difference is that I--an absolute beginner--figured out *our* problem after a quick trip over to **google**. (*Man, they let you search for **anything** over there!*)

This, when coupled with your follow-up appeal exactly two *months* after your initial posting, suggests to me that you would prefer to minimize--as much as possible--the usual hardship associated with owning and operating your own computer-machine-thingy.

As a result, with respect to your initial **IDLE/pandas** issue, your best best bet is to forget about messing around with **easy_install**, etc. Instead, go head on down to **Continuum Analytics** and pick up your very own (free) copy of [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads/), which has got more packages than you can shake a stick at! (Including, I might add, **pandas**, **numpy**, **scipy**, **statsmodels**, **matplotlib**, **IPython**, *and many more*). And the best part is that it all comes bundled together as a single easy-to-download file. Trust me, it will save you a lot of headaches if you just download everything all at once.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's requiring the person to download and install a whole lot more stuff than they actually need to.

Answer (score 0):

Panda does not work with python 2.7 , do you will need python 3.6 or higer